# TRUE or FALSE? Eliminating z from x + 2y + 3z = 2, 3x + 2y + 3z = 6 and 2x + 3y = 5 gives x + 2y = 2 .

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is the following statement true or false?
>
> Eliminating $z$ from:
> $x + 2y + 3z = 2$,
> $3x + 2y + 3z = 6$ and,
> $2x + 3y = 5$;
> gives $x + 2y = 2$.

I just subtracted first equation from the second which gives $x = 2$, I don't know how to proceed thereafter. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.themathpage.com/alg/simultaneous-equations.htm

Comment: If I substract equation 1 from 2, I get $\;2x=4\implies x=2\;$ ... and then third equation gives $\;y=1/3\;$ ...and etc.

Comment: But from 4th equation you will get $$y=0$$ please check your question.

Comment: Seems like if the question itself has got errors. Different values of $y$ can be obtained using different ways.

Answer (score 1):

As you found value of $x$ after that,

$2x + 3y = 5$

Put value of $x=2$ in above equation,

$4+3y = 5$

$3y = 1$

$y=\frac 13$

Then you can put value of $x, y$ in resultant equation $x+2y=2$. Value of $x, y$ doesn't satisfy. So answer is false.

Answer (score 0):

i would use the Gauss algorithm, multiplying the first equation by $-3$ and adding to the second one we34 get
$$2y+3z=0$$ (after dividing by (-2))
multiplying the first by $-2$ and adding go the third:
$$-y-6z=1$$ multiplying this equation by $-2$ and adding to the one obove we have $$-9z=2$$
can you proceed?